# Is throwing a ball upwards an isolated or non-isolated system?

Tags: energy-conservation

We have to write a lab report on an experiment where a ball is thrown upwards and it's motion is detected by a motion sensor, i am just confused whether the system is isolated or non-isolated

Comment: What's your definition of "isolated" or "non-isolated"?

Comment: Isolated = " a system where no energy crosses the system boundary by any method"

Comment: Well, then I suppose that the answer would depend on whether your system consists of just (a) the ball or (b) the ball and Earth because the ball does gain gravitational potential energy as it rises upwards.

Comment: The system consists of the ball and the earth but im just wondering, if i throw the ball upwards, isnt that an external force? so it would be non isolated?

Comment: Good point. Yes, if the system just consists of the ball and Earth then the act of throwing the ball upward would be a momentary external force. Oftentimes, though, these kind of problems consider the motion of the object starting from the instant after the ball is released. That way, the momentary external force is done away with and replaced by an initial velocity condition on the object, and so the system can be considered to be isolated (since the subsequent motion of the object doesn't depend on anything outside the system).

Answer (score 1):

Normally, an isolated system means that no energy, momentum or angular momentum enters of leaves the system. These quantities are conserved for the system. The best way to answer the question of whether isolated or not is to imagine a boundary around the system and ask: does any energy, momentum or angular momentum pass through it? OR: are there only interactions between members of the system alone, or do some parts of the system interact with things outside the system?

By this thinking, a ball in flight is clearly not isolated: the Earth is imparting a constant force on it (in the Newtonian framework) from outside the system, so its momentum is changing. When the system comprises both ball and Earth, momentum, energy and angular momentum conservation is restored.

Again, even when the ball is being thrown, the system comprising Earth, thrower and ball is isolated. The ball thrusts back on the thrower, whose feet thrust downwards on the Earth as it is being accelerated. Momentum, energy and angular momentum for the whole system are again all conserved.

Now we meet a subtlety. If, by isolated, you mean only "energy conserving" then a ball in flight is isolated: the sum of its gravitational potential and kinetic energy is indeed constant. But this is an unusual definition of "isolated".